# Search and Replace strings within double quotes

Tags: windows, string, vbscript

How can we search and replace strings in doubles quotes in a file using vbscript?

For example: "thisisstring" is this possible to search thisisstring to replace with "wearestrings"?

Comment: SO is not a place where we read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954) to you.

Comment: A great apologize , I think my concern is misunderstood , what i am concerned that how could we search and replace anyword (user has no idea about the words enclosed ) which is enclosed by any special characters , Here i have given  the special char as  " " .

Comment: Do you want to replace arbitrary words or specific words? Between any set of special characters or between double quotes. Please be specific (examples will help). Also show the code you currently have. As it stands your question is both unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This a little example using **[the function Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954)**

```
Option Explicit
Dim Message,MyString,ReplaceString,NewMessageString
Message = "Hello ""thisisstring"" Example"
MyString = DblQuote("thisisstring")
ReplaceString = DblQuote("wearestrings")
NewMessageString = Replace(Message,MyString,ReplaceString,1)
wscript.echo Message & VbcrLF & NewMessageString
'*****************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*****************************************************
```